# With EmberJS, how do I get a model using the findProperty/find method?

Tags: ember.js

How do I find the relevant model where its name equals something? I've tried: `this.get('content').findProperty('name', name)`, but it doesn't appear to work. I suppose it'd work if my enumerable wasn't stuffed full of models...

Comment: Can you provide more code and create a JSFiddle? What does your `content` array look like?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I don't know how to support EmberJS in JSFiddle, because it doesn't appear to be in the list of supported libraries. But something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fxQ28/

Comment: You can use http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/eTcDu/ as a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `findProperty` / `find` on your `Ember.ArrayController` instance, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/kPmHr/:

```js
App.peopleController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [
        App.Person.create({ name: 'Adam' }),
        App.Person.create({ name: 'John' }),
        App.Person.create({ name: 'Adam' })
    ],

    findByName: function(name) {
        var found = this.findProperty('name', name);
        console.log('found model %@'.fmt(found));
    }
});

App.peopleController.findByName('Adam');​
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! I was just updating my JSFiddle to support EmberJS: http://jsfiddle.net/eTcDu/3/ I wasn't being lazy in not doing it :( Just didn't know how. I'm sorry you had to write all of that code, but thank you! That's perfect.

Comment: Absolutely no problem at all! This is your first question on StackOverflow so no need to worry :) Just as a hint for future questions: if you provide code and an example which can be run, for example using JSFiddle, chances to get an answer are higher.